# Filtering keycodes with EVIOCSMASK

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I would like to receive only `EV_KEY` events with codes `224` and `225` when reading from a `/dev/input/event*` file. How do I do that?

---

As far as I can tell, I need to run `ioctl(fd, EVIOCSMASK, &mask)`, but I don't understand how to set up a `struct input_mask` with my specifications.

I tried setting `type` to `EV_KEY`, but that seems to filter **out** `EV_KEY`, and if I set anything in `codes_*` (such as an array of codes and a pointer to it), then `ioctl` returns `-1`.

Comment: Please post the code you've.  It is very difficult to help you without the nitty gritty details.  Thanks!

Comment: you can do it using simple input_event structure, read from device and check needed key-code

Comment: From what i deduce try this: enable only EV_KEY by filtering EV-bits with type=0 `ioctl(fd,EVIOSMASK,&(struct input_mask){0,1,(uint64_t[1]){1<<EV_KEY});`, then enable only 224 and 225 with `len=KEY_CNT/sizeof(uint64_t); ioctl(fd,EVIOCSMASK,&(struct input_mask){EV_KEY,len,(uint64_t[len]){ [224/64] = 1<<(224%64)|1<<(225%64)});` Check evdev sources [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg30924.html) or [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/evdev.c#L991), I don't get it good, maybe someone else will get the sources better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [include/linux/input.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input.h):

> The event mask is a per-client mask that specifies which events are
>   forwarded to the client. Each event code is represented by a single bit
>   in the event mask. If the bit is set, the event is passed to the client
>   normally.

In other words:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define  ULONG_BITS  (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))

static void set_bit(unsigned long bits[], size_t bit)
{
    bits[bit / ULONG_BITS] |= 1UL << (bit % ULONG_BITS);
}

static void set_keymask(int fd)
{
    unsigned long      bits[(KEY_CNT + ULONG_BITS - 1) / ULONG_BITS] = { 0 };
    struct input_mask  mask;

    mask.type = EV_KEY;
    mask.codes_size = KEY_CNT;
    mask.codes_ptr = &bits;

    /* Only report KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN and KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP */
    set_bit(bits, KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN);
    set_bit(bits, KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP);

    if (ioctl(fd, EVIOSMASK, &mask))
        return errno;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to set the mask

```
    struct input_mask mask;

    bitset_put(types, KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN); // event ID 224
    bitset_put(types, KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP); // event ID 225

    mask = (struct input_mask) {
            .type = EV_KEY,
            .codes_size = sizeof(types),
            .codes_ptr = PTR_TO_UINT64(types),
    };

    if (ioctl(b->fd, EVIOCSMASK, &mask) < 0)
    {
      //log the error here and check errno to get a nice description about the error
    }...
```

As you can see the code is easy to understand, you declare which event type to receive (here ´EV_KEY´) and then an array to filter out which events which you can get [here](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/include/linux/input.h)